# How to visualize LSTM cell Tensorflow Matplotlib?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, visualization, lstm

I have created LSTM based training model:

```
def load_data_old(df_, seq_len):
    data_raw = df_.values 
    data = []
    for index in range(len(data_raw) - seq_len): 
        data.append(data_raw[index: index + seq_len])

    data = np.array(data);
    valid_set_size = int(np.round(valid_set_size_percentage/100*data.shape[0]));  
    test_set_size = int(np.round(test_set_size_percentage/100*data.shape[0]));
    train_set_size = data.shape[0] - (valid_set_size + test_set_size);

    x_train = data[:train_set_size,:-1,:-1]
    y_train = data[:train_set_size,-1,-1:]

    x_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size,:-1,:-1]
    y_valid = data[train_set_size:train_set_size+valid_set_size,-1,-1:]

    x_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:,:-1,:-1]
    y_test = data[train_set_size+valid_set_size:,-1,-1:]
    return[x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid, x_test, y_test]

x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid, x_test, y_test = load_data(df,seq_len)
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs],name="input")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_outputs],name="output")
n_inputs = x_train.shape[2]
n_outputs = y_train.shape[1]
layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, use_peepholes = True,name="layer"+str(layer))
             for layer in range(n_layers)]
multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
outputs = tf.identity(outputs[:,n_steps-1,:], name="prediction")
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y)) # loss function = mean squared error 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Suppose the input data is:

```
input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7,input8,output
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,-1
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-1
5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1
6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,0
7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1
```

I want to visualize the sequences what is going to the LSTM and what interpretation LSTM is calculating out of the sequences that has been given as input.

Kindly, let me know how I can do that. What I need to do.

Comment: The person who flagged me for closing and reasoning as too broad, do you have no solution for what I asked? If it is too broad then can't you help me with a smaller stuff. At least help me figure it out.

Comment: While I didn't cast any vote, I reckon the question is too broad as it is currently stated. What exactly do you want to visualize? What do you mean by "what is going to the LSTM and what interpretation LSTM is calculating"? As you surely know, neural networks are quite opaque (this is in fact an active research topic). You may ask about how to produce a specific kind of plot or visualization, but there is no "standard RNN visualization" that will make everything clear. [This popular blog post](https://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) has some ideas you might find inspiring.