# 3D array to 2d array from pandas Python and Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have created the array from a csv using pandas and numpy.
This is my code that convert 2D csv to 3D array:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as npp
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
>>> df_mat = df.values
>>> seq_len = 3
>>> data=[]
>>> for index in range(len(df_mat) - seq_len):
...     data.append(df_mat[index: index + seq_len])
...
>>> data = np.array(data)
>>> data.shape
(4, 3, 9)
```

The csv is used is:

```
input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7,input8,output
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,-1
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-1
5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1
6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,0
7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,1
```

Now I want to get the 3D array back to 2D array format.
Kindly, let me know how I can I do that. Not getting any clue.

Comment: Think that should be - `for index in range(len(df_mat) - seq_len + 1):` instead to cover all subarrays?

Comment: The same as previous when it was a row and column. (7, 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice on the `0th` rows along each each *block* until the last block and stack with the last one -

```
np.vstack((data[np.arange(data.shape[0]-1),0],data[-1]))
```

Output with given sample data -

```
In [24]: np.vstack((data[np.arange(data.shape[0]-1),0],data[-1]))
Out[24]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, -1],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, -1],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,  1],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,  0],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  1]], dtype=int64)
```

Or slice `0th` rows across all blocks and stack with the last block skipping the first row -

```
In [28]: np.vstack((data[np.arange(data.shape[0]),0],data[-1,1:]))
Out[28]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, -1],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, -1],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,  1],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,  0],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I am not getting the last row sir. How you are getting it I didn't got that.

Comment: @JafferWilson [`Read my comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805743/3d-array-to-2d-array-from-pandas-python-and-numpy/54805860?noredirect=1#comment96387926_54805743)?

Comment: Thank you for the insights sir.

Comment: Sir,  can you please help me on these question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789287/how-to-visualize-lstm-cell-tensorflow-matplotlib and  https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/10781/how-my-lstm-is-making-association-between-the-columns? From your profile I guess you can help me.

Comment: @JafferWilson Sorry mate, don't think I have the expertise on those tags.